# How to concatenate column values in second row if cells in a range contains a specific text/character

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56466346/how-to-concatenate-column-titles-if-cells-in-a-range-contains-a-specific-text-ch) in 2019 and got a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56467170/19386858).

I am trying to create a list based on specific criteria (if the cell contains "*").

Instead of using the title row (row 1), I want to use the values in row 2.
I added another row on top of my original table. So, what was row 1 is now row 2.

How can the UDF in the answer be edited so the text in row 2 gets concatenated?

I am trying to automatically create the fourth column:

```
    A       B       C           D
(1) 
(2) text1   Text2   Text3       List
(3) Bob*    Mike    John*       Text1; Text3
(4) Jane    Lisa*   Brenda*     Text2; Text3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have fine answers, but if you are set on VBA and you want to somehow convert the very old UDF (as you requested), then try:

```
Function CONCATENATEIF(LST As Range, RNG As Range, CON As String) As String

For x = 1 To RNG.Cells.Count
    If InStr(1, RNG.Cells(1, x).Value, CON) > 0 Then CONCATENATEIF = CONCATENATEIF & LST.Cells(1, x).Value & "; "
Next
If CONCATENATEIF <> "" Then
    CONCATENATEIF = Left(CONCATENATEIF, Len(CONCATENATEIF) - 2)
End If

End Function
```

Use like: `=CONCATENATEIF(A$1:C$1,A2:C2,"*")` and drag down...

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to solve this in VBA? If you have Excel 365, the formula is fairly straightforward - you could, for example, `MAP` the array, looking for an asterix, and then `TEXTJOIN` the resulting map. Something like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE, MAP(A3:C3,LAMBDA(v,IF(RIGHT(v,1)="*", INDEX($A$2:$C$2,1, COLUMN(v)),""))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,FILTER($A$2:$C$2,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("~*",A3:C3))))
```

If your version of excel support `LAMBDA()` function then try below formula for one go.

```
=BYROW(A3:C4,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,FILTER($A$2:$C$2,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("~*",a))))))
```

[image]